# Send data from a UserControl in a Popup to the parent Page

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-c++, user-controls

I have a Popup that's just a UserControl which is basically just a form to fill out with a 'Done' button on it.  I can't find a way to send the data from the form to the Page so that I can parse and use the data to create a specific element.  Basically when the 'Done' button is clicked I can't find a way to send or even access the Page to store the data.

Binding doesn't seem to be the way to go either as when the 'Done' button is clicked what happens is the Page creates another UserControl populated with the data that was received from the form in the popup.  Since binding doesn't seem to fit my problem, passing data would be next but since I can't find a way to reference the Page I can't get this solution to work either.

the Page is just this:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Popup IsLightDismissEnabled="True">
        <local:PopupMenu/>
    </Popup>
</Button>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,340,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="55" Width="455"/>
```

The UserControl is basically:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="SimpleShop.PopupMenu"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SimpleShop"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Height="800" Width="1295">
<TextBlock text="Enter A Number" Fontsize="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="40" Width="200"  />
<TextBox x:Name="Number1" Text="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="40" Width="200"  />
<TextBlock text="Enter A Number" Fontsize="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="40" Width="200"  />
<TextBox x:Name="Number2" Text="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="40" Width="200" />
<Button x:Name="AddItemButton" Content="Button" FontSize="24"  Height="40" Width="110" Click="AddItemButton_Click" />
</UserControl>
```

So what happens is when the button on the page is pressed the popup appears, after 2 numbers are entered and the button on the popup is pressed the textbox on the page is updated with the result of the 2 entered numbers being multiplied and the popup is closed.  The problem i'm having is updating the textbox on the page after the button on the popup is pressed.  I can't find a way to point to or reference the textbox.

Comment: The question is too abstracted to answer.  Please post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I apologize, I've added a sample code and summarized what is happening and what I'm attempting to accomplish.  I would add the actual code but I've been informed I'm not allowed to do that, so this is the best I can get away with.

Comment: No prob, thanks for the update.  One more question, though -- how are you actually displaying the popup?  Somewhere in code-behind presumably?

Comment: Ya i'ts just in the click even for the Button on the Page, its right above the opening <Popup> tag... I should have named the button and the popup, but the code is this:

if (!MyPopUp->IsOpen) { MyPopUp->IsOpen = true; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need two parts:

1. Notification when the popup closes
2. Access to the result of the popup form.

For the first, consider using the [`Closed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.closed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, ie:

```
<Popup IsLightDismissEnabled="True" Closed="Popup_Closed">
    <local:PopupMenu x:Name="popupUserControl"/>
</Popup>
```

For the second, I'd just expose a property on `PopupMenu` that gives you the result.  Something like this:

```
public partial class PopupMenu : UserControl
{
    public double Result { get; private set; }

    public AddItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Result = double.Parse(Number1.Value) + double.Parse(Number2.Value);
    }
}
```

Then you can set the text as needed, in the `Closed` event handler:

```
private void Popup_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtResult.Text = popupUserControl.Result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, sorry I'm not that familiar with C#... I can read it and know what it does but I don't always understand how it's working.  In this case, the get and set are for a double var named Result, correct?  Also, in C++ I would just create a local var of type double in the class and then create 2 functions name getResult and setResult to simulate this process?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @user3164339 yes, exactly.  The `{ get; set; }` is C# shorthand, called auto-implemented properties:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: I guess I have one more question, the PopupClosing function you posted is that the Closed="Popup_Closed" that you used in the Popup declaration?  Also, just so I understand why this works instead of binding the txtResult.Text to something on the UserControl:  this works because the popup is declared in the same scope as txtResult?  I think a better way of putting that would be, I was having trouble binding txtResult.Text to the popupUserControl as every time I tried to set the Source and Path of the binding in the popupUserControl the txtResult wasn't showing up as accessible.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo -- should be `Popup_Closed`.  To the second question: binding vs using code-behind are a bit different.  I don't know off the top of my head when code-behind doesn't work; but I know that, for binding to work, the target (`ElementName`) has to be in the same namescope: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx